# Android default media player "start" after "stop" error (com.android.music.musicservicecommand)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mediaplayer, media-player, default

When I send to the default player

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
i.putExtra("command", "play");
ACTIVITY.sendBroadcast(i);
```

it starts to play. When I send

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
        i.putExtra("command", "stop");
        ACTIVITY.sendBroadcast(i);
```

It stops. But when I try to play again then it doesn't play. It just plays for a second and then stops again. I saw on the log I get two intents. The

```
intent.getBooleanExtra("playing", false);
```

The first time is "true" and then is "false". This isn't happening when I try the "togglepause". I also noticed that when I send play both the Android music app and the Google Play music starts.

I figured out that Google Play music was causing that. Apparently, both apps get the intent and when I send play, the music player answers with `isPlaying = true` and the Google Play music `isPlaying = false`. How to fix that or how to send or to receive only fron the default player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little late but posting for others who are searching for this. You can control default media player by sending an ordered broadcast to the system that a media button has been pressed and released.The following code will play or pause music depending on the current state:

```
  long eventtime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis(); 
  Intent downIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null); 
  KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, 
  KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0); 
  downIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, downEvent); 
  sendOrderedBroadcast(downIntent, null); 

  Intent upIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null); 
  KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, 
  KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0); 
  upIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, upEvent); 
  sendOrderedBroadcast(upIntent, null);
```

The same way you can alert the system that the next or previous track button has been pressed.

Comment: I just tried that but the keys doesnt work all the time. Sometimes they work sometimes they don't. I put a log message to show up every time i press the button. The log shows the "play" and "pause" messages but the music doesnt stop. Maybe if i push it several times it then stops. Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: It works perfectly for me and i have tried it in many phones. just in case....try to add a delay for the button up event. KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime+100, eventtime+100, 
  KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0); let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ok thanks! It was my mistake i only sent the downevent or the upevent. Now with this it works. Do you know how to send the next / previous also? Do I need to send them in pairs too?

Comment: it's the same thing just change the key code.  KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT or KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS

Comment: @Anonymous :  
How can I play a particular file with default player.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363026/play-mp3-in-google-play-music

Answer (score 0):

Instead of issuing the "stop" command, have you tried "pause" ?

```
   Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
   i.putExtra("command", "pause");
```

It seems possible to call pause/play as many times as you like and it restarts just fine.

Comment: How can I play a particular file with default player