# Start com.android.music.musicservicecommand

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-broadcast

Is there any way to start playing with the default music player a song across different brands' devices?

I tried the following code and pausing works successfully if the service already runs. However play command never initiates.

For example I test this on a Xperia S. Pause works, but play never starts the default (Walkman app) player (service).

```
final AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

Button player = (Button) findViewById(R.id.player);
player.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Button music:","clicked!");

        if(mAudioManager.isMusicActive()) {
            Log.v("Button music:","paused!");
            Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
            i.putExtra("command", "pause");
            MainActivity.this.sendBroadcast(i);
        }else{
            Log.v("Button music:","starts!");
            Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
            i.putExtra("command", "play");
            MainActivity.this.sendBroadcast(i);
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
   //"songsList" is an array with paths of all the songs in the sdcard
Uri uri = Uri.parse(songsList.get(0));
String type = "audio/mp3";
intent.setDataAndType(uri, type);
startActivity(intent);
```

It will directly open your music player & start that selected/particular song. If it doesn't work, then you can replace intent name by "android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC"

Comment: It shows an error : android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Kannil Kannil.mp3 typ=audio/mp3 }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    long eventtime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis(); 
    Intent downIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null); 
    KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, 
    KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0); 
    downIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, downEvent); 
    sendOrderedBroadcast(downIntent, null); 

    Intent upIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null); 
    KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, 
    KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0); 
    upIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, upEvent); 
    sendOrderedBroadcast(upIntent, null);
```

Link : [Android default media player "start" after "stop" error (com.android.music.musicservicecommand)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491678/android-default-media-player-start-after-stop-error-com-android-music-music)